# How to mine text form an openEdX forum?

Tags: openedx

I would like to collect all the message on an openEdX forum for quantitative analysis. What are the most frequent specialized words uses, etc. But how to download / mine an openEdX forum ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have access to the Open edX platform? you need to extract text from all threads and all messages. The library for interacting with the forums is in `lms.lib.comment_client`. For example, to obtain all threads from a specific course, execute:

```
lms.lib.comment_client.Thread.search({
    'course_id': course_id,
})
```

For each thread, you must then iterate over the comments and extract their body, and eventually their title. I believe you can obtain the comments from a thread using the `thread.to_dict()` method.